# Voltage drop when load is applied

Tags: power-supply, power

I have four 200AH batteries connected in a series-parallel form. These batteries are charged using an alternator mounted on a running engine. The purpose of these batteries is for lighting.

There are about 25 lamps each containing 60 watt bulbs. Distance between the loads and the batteries is about 20 metres. The issue that I'm having is that: whenever I switch more than one light on, voltage drops immediately. I cant seem to figure out what's the cause of this.

Comment: What a milli volt?

Comment: What voltage are your batteries ? What voltage are your lamps ? How much current is flowing ? My guess is that your cables are too thin for the current causing voltage drop.

Comment: Does it drop and then come back?

Comment: And, voltage drops where? As measured across the batteries? At the lamp?

Comment: @IC_designer_Rimpelbekkie; they're all 24volts batteries, the lamps are also 24v. I'm using 16mm welding cables. @Voitcus; yes, as soon I switch off the lights, the voltage rises up immediately. @NickJohnson; as measured across the batteries and according to a voltmeter I fixed onto my switch panel

Comment: If the voltage *directly across the batteries* is dropping, then the batteries are bad. Their internal resistance is far too high.

Answer (score 3):

A 24V, 60W bulb requires 2.5A of current. 25 such bulbs requires a total of 62.5A.

If you want to deliver this current with a voltage drop of no more than 10% (2.4V), then you need to use wires that have a total resistance of no more than 2.4V / 62.5A = 38.4 mΩ.

Assuming you're using copper wires with a total length of 40 meters (out and back), they would have to have a diameter of about 5mm, or roughly AWG4 — i.e., welding cable.

Comment: thanks @DaveTweed, I'm actually using 16mm welding cables, I've been observing the temp but nothing unusual. the alternator mounted on the running engine is 55A alternator.